# No puedo usar $router dentro de store (vuex)

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

tengo mi **main.js**:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'

// Import Bootstrap an BootstrapVue CSS files (order is important)
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Chat from "./components/Chat";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import Register from "./components/Register";
import  {store} from "./store/store"
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

// Make BootstrapVue available throughout your project
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
// Optionally install the BootstrapVue icon components plugin
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: Chat,
      beforeEnter(to,from,next){
        if (store.getters.getToken){
          next();
        }
        else {
          router.push('/login');
        }
    }
  },
  { path: '/login', component: Login },
  { path: '/register', component: Register }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode:'history',
  linkExactActiveClass: 'is-active',
  routes // short for `routes: routes`,
});

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

**Mi vuex (store.js):**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from "axios";


Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state:{
        auth_user:{},
        users:[],
        messages:[],
        backend_url_base:' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'
    },
    mutations:{
        setAuthUser(state, user){
            state.auth_user = user;
        },
        clearAuth(state){
            state.auth_user = null;
        },
        addMessage(state,newMessage){
            state.messages.push(newMessage);
        },
        addMessages(state,newMessages){
            newMessages.forEach((message)=>this.addMessage(message));
        }
    },
    getters:{
        getAuthUser: state => state.auth_user,
        getUsers: state => state.users,
        getMessages: state => state.messages,
        getToken: state => state.auth_user!= null ? state.auth_user.token : null,
        getUrlBase: state => state.backend_url_base,
    },
    actions:{
        login({commit,getters},user){

            let router = this.$router;
            let url = getters.getUrlBase+'user/login';
            axios.post(url,user)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    if (response.status == 200){
                        let user = response.data.user;
                        user.token =response.data.token;
                        commit('setAuthUser',user);
                    }
                    router.push('/');
                })
                .catch((error)=>{
                    console.log('error al iniciar sesion',error);
                    router.push('/login');
                });

        }
    }
});
```

Y quiero hacer que cuando se logee redireccione al inicio : `router.push('/');` , pero no consigo que detecte mi router que tengo configurado en `main.js` he probado de mil maneras. Pero siempre me dice :

```
store.js?07a4:53 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at eval (store.js?07a4:53)
```

Si os fijais en la instacia de Vue pongo antes el `router` que el `store` para ver si pudiera ser problema de declarar antes una cosa que otra, pero no es eso.

Comment: this.$router tiene algo?

Comment: @gbianchi deberia de obtener el global de router, tambien he probado a exportarlo desde main.js e imortarlo aqui pero no da solucion

Comment: deberia? lo verificaste de alguna forma? porque el error es que no esta definido...

Comment: @gbianchi si te dijas desde main.js lo estoy exportando, y luego importando en el fichero que tengo el problema